# Fill null values based on the values of the other column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to fill the null values of a column based on the values of other column. 
I want to fill it as 0 if other column is 0 or else leave it as null.

```
A  B   C
1  1   0
0 NAN  2
2 NAN  0

I want the result as

A   B   C
1   1   0
0  NAN  2
2   0   0
```

Comment: so is `B` based on `C`?

Comment: yes B is based on C

Comment: Does `df.B.fillna(df.C[df.C == 0], inplace=True) ` give you what you want?

Comment: no, it doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

This should make the trick:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['C']== 0, 0, np.nan)
```

Comment: This would not produce the desired output, specifically when B is not `np.nan`

Comment: From my reading of the Q - only want to do this where B is NaN - not unconditionally overwrite B where C is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `np.where`

```
df['B']=np.where(df.B.isnull()&df.C.eq(0),0,df.B)
```